# CSS: line behind text gradient

Tags: css

I am trying to make a double line behind gradient text.

- Text gradient is made by setting background with a gradient then use a clip path to trace the text.
- Line behind text is usually made by adding a line in the middle of the parent element, then setting the child to parent background color.

I met some issue since both of them need to use the property of `background`.

Please read following code:

```css
body{
    background: grey;
}

@keyframes textBG {
  0% {
    background-position-x: 0;
  }
  100% {
    background-position-x: 10000px;
  }
}

.line-behind.background {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.line-behind.background::before {
  border-top: 2px solid #dfdfdf;
  content: "";
  margin: 0 auto;
  /* this centers the line to the full width specified */
  position: absolute;
  /* positioning must be absolute here, and relative positioning must be applied to the parent */
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 95%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.line-behind.background span {
  /* to hide the lines from behind the text, you have to set the background color the same as the container */
  background: grey;
  padding: 0 15px;
}
.line-behind.double::before {
  /* this is just to undo the ::before styling from above */
  border-top: none;
}

.line-behind.double::after {
  border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 red;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 red;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 red;
  content: "";
  margin: 0 auto;
  /* this centers the line to the full width specified */
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 95%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.text-gradient {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size:42px;
  color: transparent;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #1e5799, #2ce0bf, #76dd2c, #dba62b, #e02cbf, #1e5799);
  background-size: 1000px 100%;
  animation: textBG 15s linear infinite;
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
}

.text-gradient::selection {
  color: white;
  background: darkorchid;
}

#shelf-image{
    position: fixed;
    max-width: 100vw;
    max-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
}

#shelf-image-title{
    width: 100vw;
    height: 8vh;
    text-align: center;
}

#shelf-section{
    width: 100vw;
    height: 92vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    border: dashed;
}

#shelf-image-container{
    overflow: auto;
    width: 80vmin;
    height: 80vmin;
    border: double;
}

#shelf-image-info{
    width: 50vmin;
    height: 80vmin;
    border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="shelf-image">
    <div id="shelf-image-title">
        <div class="line-behind background double">
            <span>
                <h1 class="text-gradient">
                    Settings
                </h1>
            </span>
        </h1>
    </div>

    <!-- <div id="shelf-image-title">
        <div class="line-behind background double">
            <span class="text-gradient">
                Settings
            </span>
        </h1>
    </div> -->

    <div id="shelf-section">
        <div id="shelf-image-container">
            <svg id="settings_icon" viewBox="0 0 46.57 46.96" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" fill="white"><path d="M31.36 23.43L31.02 25.83L30 28.08L28.29 29.95L25.98 31.16L23.37 31.41L20.86 30.66L18.83 29.08L17.46 26.99L16.78 24.64L16.78 22.22L17.46 19.87L18.83 17.78L20.86 16.2L23.37 15.45L25.98 15.71L28.29 16.91L30 18.78L31.02 21.03L31.36 23.43Z" stroke="black" fill="none" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" /><path d="M21.02 10.83L20.65 0L32.59 0.4L30 11.13L35.37 17.31L45.19 11.64L46.57 23.89L36.2 23.28L34.44 32.59L43.8 38.56L32.96 46.96L28.52 35.63L17.87 34.92L15.09 46.56L4.07 38.16L13.43 30.97L12.04 23.48L0 24.8L4.72 8.3L14.63 15.38L21.2 10.63" stroke="black" fill="none" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" /></svg>
        </div>
        <div id="shelf-image-info">
            <h2>Here</h2>
            <p>Here</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried to separate `text-gradient` class to a `h1` instead of `span` but it didn't work.

If someone can offer some help, I will be so grateful.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? The line only behind the text?

Comment: @ John: Sorry perhaps I wasn't clear. The line goes behind the text should not be seen in code snippets above

Comment: I still don't completely understand.  You want the line exactly how it is now, just to not be visible behind the text. So the line will be only be to the left and to the right of the text correct?

Comment: Yes exactly, I want the part of the line goes behind the text to disappear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest method would be to add `display: inline-block;` to the parent of the `h1` (the `span`). This allows the span to conform to the bounding box of the text and use its background to block the line.

```css
body{
    background: grey;
}

@keyframes textBG {
  0% {
    background-position-x: 0;
  }
  100% {
    background-position-x: 10000px;
  }
}

.line-behind.background {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.line-behind.background::before {
  border-top: 2px solid #dfdfdf;
  content: "";
  margin: 0 auto;
  /* this centers the line to the full width specified */
  position: absolute;
  /* positioning must be absolute here, and relative positioning must be applied to the parent */
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 95%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.line-behind.background span {
  /* to hide the lines from behind the text, you have to set the background color the same as the container */
  background: grey;
  padding: 0 15px;
}
.line-behind.double::before {
  /* this is just to undo the ::before styling from above */
  border-top: none;
}

.line-behind.double::after {
  border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 red;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 red;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 red;
  content: "";
  margin: 0 auto;
  /* this centers the line to the full width specified */
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 95%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.text-gradient {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size:42px;
  color: transparent;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #1e5799, #2ce0bf, #76dd2c, #dba62b, #e02cbf, #1e5799);
  background-size: 1000px 100%;
  animation: textBG 15s linear infinite;
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
}

.text-gradient::selection {
  color: white;
  background: darkorchid;
}

#shelf-image{
    position: fixed;
    max-width: 100vw;
    max-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
}

#shelf-image-title{
    width: 100vw;
    height: 8vh;
    text-align: center;
}

#shelf-section{
    width: 100vw;
    height: 92vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    border: dashed;
}

#shelf-image-container{
    overflow: auto;
    width: 80vmin;
    height: 80vmin;
    border: double;
}

#shelf-image-info{
    width: 50vmin;
    height: 80vmin;
    border: 1px solid;
}

.text-wrap {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="shelf-image">
    <div id="shelf-image-title">
        <div class="line-behind background double">
            <span class="text-wrap">
                <h1 class="text-gradient">
                    Settings
                </h1>
            </span>
        </h1>
    </div>

    <!-- <div id="shelf-image-title">
        <div class="line-behind background double">
            <span class="text-gradient">
                Settings
            </span>
        </h1>
    </div> -->

    <div id="shelf-section">
        <div id="shelf-image-container">
            <svg id="settings_icon" viewBox="0 0 46.57 46.96" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" fill="white"><path d="M31.36 23.43L31.02 25.83L30 28.08L28.29 29.95L25.98 31.16L23.37 31.41L20.86 30.66L18.83 29.08L17.46 26.99L16.78 24.64L16.78 22.22L17.46 19.87L18.83 17.78L20.86 16.2L23.37 15.45L25.98 15.71L28.29 16.91L30 18.78L31.02 21.03L31.36 23.43Z" stroke="black" fill="none" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" /><path d="M21.02 10.83L20.65 0L32.59 0.4L30 11.13L35.37 17.31L45.19 11.64L46.57 23.89L36.2 23.28L34.44 32.59L43.8 38.56L32.96 46.96L28.52 35.63L17.87 34.92L15.09 46.56L4.07 38.16L13.43 30.97L12.04 23.48L0 24.8L4.72 8.3L14.63 15.38L21.2 10.63" stroke="black" fill="none" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" /></svg>
        </div>
        <div id="shelf-image-info">
            <h2>Here</h2>
            <p>Here</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this work for you.  You can kind of hack this to work by making a div before and a div after your text which generates the line. And then styling it so the line is to the left and right of the text and the text is centered.  Take a look at this example I made:

```css
body{
    background: grey;
}

@keyframes textBG {
  0% {
    background-position-x: 0;
  }
  100% {
    background-position-x: 10000px;
  }
}

.line-behind.background {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.line-behind.background::before {
  border-top: 2px solid #dfdfdf;
  content: "";
  margin: 0 auto;
  /* this centers the line to the full width specified */
  position: absolute;
  /* positioning must be absolute here, and relative positioning must be applied to the parent */
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 95%;
  z-index: -1;
}



.line-behind.background span {
  /* to hide the lines from behind the text, you have to set the background color the same as the container */
  background: grey;
  padding: 0 15px;
}
.line-behind.double::before {
  /* this is just to undo the ::before styling from above */
  border-top: none;
}

.theline {
  border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 red;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 red;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 red;
  content: "";
  margin: 0 auto;
  /* this centers the line to the full width specified */
  top: 45%;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 100%;
}

.text-gradient {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size:42px;
  color: transparent;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #1e5799, #2ce0bf, #76dd2c, #dba62b, #e02cbf, #1e5799);
  animation: textBG 15s linear infinite;
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
}

.text-gradient::selection {
  color: white;
  background: darkorchid;
}

#shelf-image{
    position: fixed;
    max-width: 100vw;
    max-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
}

#shelf-image-title{
    width: 100vw;
    height: 8vh;
    text-align: center;
}

#shelf-section{
    width: 100vw;
    height: 92vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    border: dashed;
}

#shelf-image-container{
    overflow: auto;
    width: 80vmin;
    height: 80vmin;
    border: double;
}

#shelf-image-info{
    width: 50vmin;
    height: 80vmin;
    border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="shelf-image">
    <div id="shelf-image-title">
        <div class="line-behind background double">
            <span>
                <h1 class="text-gradient">
                    <div class="theline"></div>Settings<div class="theline"></div>
                </h1>
                
            </span>
        
    </div>

    <!-- <div id="shelf-image-title">
        <div class="line-behind background double">
            <span class="text-gradient">
                Settings
            </span>
        </h1>
    </div> -->

    <div id="shelf-section">
        <div id="shelf-image-container">
            <svg id="settings_icon" viewBox="0 0 46.57 46.96" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" fill="white"><path d="M31.36 23.43L31.02 25.83L30 28.08L28.29 29.95L25.98 31.16L23.37 31.41L20.86 30.66L18.83 29.08L17.46 26.99L16.78 24.64L16.78 22.22L17.46 19.87L18.83 17.78L20.86 16.2L23.37 15.45L25.98 15.71L28.29 16.91L30 18.78L31.02 21.03L31.36 23.43Z" stroke="black" fill="none" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" /><path d="M21.02 10.83L20.65 0L32.59 0.4L30 11.13L35.37 17.31L45.19 11.64L46.57 23.89L36.2 23.28L34.44 32.59L43.8 38.56L32.96 46.96L28.52 35.63L17.87 34.92L15.09 46.56L4.07 38.16L13.43 30.97L12.04 23.48L0 24.8L4.72 8.3L14.63 15.38L21.2 10.63" stroke="black" fill="none" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" /></svg>
        </div>
        <div id="shelf-image-info">
            <h2>Here</h2>
            <p>Here</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```